# How can I solve the multiple "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field" errors I am getting?

Tags: java

I understand that this question was asked multiple times on this site but the answers given don't seem to help me. I am very new to Java.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Lab10 {

    String species, color, injuries, name, wiput, liput, locationFound, oiput;
    char gender;
    float weight, length;
    boolean hasShots, needsShots;
    int tagNumber, cageNumber, outcome;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        strayAnimal(species, color, weight, length, injuries, locationFound, name);

    }

    public static void strayAnimal(String species, String color, float weight, float length, String injuries, String locationFound, String name) {
        species = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the species of the animal: ");
        color = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the color of the animal: ");
        wiput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the weight of the animal");
        weight = Float.parseFloat(wiput);
        liput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the lenght of the animal: ");
        length = Float.parseFloat(liput);
        locationFound = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the location the animal was found(City, County, State): ");
        injuries = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the injuries the animal has seperated with commas: ");

    }
    //public static char strayAnimal() {

    //}
    public static void setOutcome(int outcome) {
        oiput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a '0' if the animal has or will be terminated or a '1' if the animal has been saved: ");
        outcome = Integer.parseInt(oiput);
    }
    public void giveShots() {
        boolean giveShots;
        if (giveShots = true) {

        }
    }
    public static void needShots() {
        boolean needShots;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a static method e.g. `setOutcome` that wants to access non-static variables like `outcome`. That is not allowed.
You have to make the variable `outcome` static or the method non-static.

Answer (score 1):

it does not make sense to have strayAnimal pass in any arguments.
After that you should be good.

It also helps to have the running class outside of the implementation

```
public class Runner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Lab10 lab = new Lab10();
        lab.strayAnimal();
    }
}
```

And the class be

```
public class Lab10 {

    String species, color, injuries, name, wiput, liput, locationFound, oiput;
    char gender;
    float weight, length;
    boolean hasShots, needsShots;
    int tagNumber, cageNumber, outcome;


    public void strayAnimal(String species, String color, float weight, float length, String injuries, String locationFound, String name) {
        species = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the species of the animal: ");
        color = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the color of the animal: ");
        wiput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the weight of the animal");
        weight = Float.parseFloat(wiput);
        liput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the lenght of the animal: ");
        length = Float.parseFloat(liput);
        locationFound = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the location the animal was found(City, County, State): ");
        injuries = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the injuries the animal has seperated with commas: ");

    }

    public void setOutcome(int outcome) {
        oiput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a '0' if the animal has or will be terminated or a '1' if the animal has been saved: ");
        outcome = Integer.parseInt(oiput);
    }
    public void giveShots() {
        boolean giveShots;
        if (giveShots = true) {

        }
    }
    public void needShots() {
        boolean needShots;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below the variable must be static

```
String species, color, injuries, name, wiput, liput, locationFound, oiput;
char gender;
float weight, length;
boolean hasShots, needsShots;
int tagNumber, cageNumber, outcome;
```

Because you cant use nonstatic variables, in a static method,

Answer (score 0):

```
String species, color, injuries, name, wiput, liput, locationFound, oiput;
char gender;
float weight, length;
boolean hasShots, needsShots;
int tagNumber, cageNumber, outcome;
```

are all non-static class members.

a method like `strayAnimals` is static. You cannot reference any non-static member from a static method. You can either define an instance of the class and use that to access the class members

```
class Lab10 {
    public Lab10 instance;

    public static Lab10 getInstance() {
         if (instance == null) instance = new Lab10();
         return instance;
    }

    ...

    public static void strayAnimal(...) {
        Lab10 instance = Lab10.getInstance();
        // now you can use instance.wiput;
    }
}
```

or make the members static. However, the second option has the side effect of breaking your non-static methods.